# I'm in the process of gathering quotes for multifunction copier leases...what questions should I be asking the sales people?

Tags: printing, printer

What sort of key questions should I be asking to determine which product/company to go with? Aside form researching the different copiers presented by the different companies (Xerox, Ricoh, Savin, and Konica Minolta) what sort of key determining factors should I be researching?

Right now I know that I need to consider things like maintenance costs, SLAs, monthly lease costs, cost of delivery/setup...but I'm not sure what else I should be considering?

I'm currently looking to get a color multifunction copier setup in two of our offices in the midatllantic region.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never thought I'd have to deal with *copiers* in a sysadmin role, but some how they fell into our IT department's purview during the last round of upgrades.  We had little warning and almost no influence on vendor/model selection.  The devices were purchased and we were told "*make these work*".  Had I involvement in the process I would have been asking about the following:

- Directory integration for user/groups/address books. (AD, LDAP, *etc*.)
- Scan-to-file output file system support. (NFS, CIFS...)
- LDAP/AD integration for user authentication (Secure printing, scan-to-profile...)
- Remote console (web-based is a plus for me) to centrally manage multiple devices.

Comment: I work for a small company (around 200 employees) so I have to handle pretty much anything that plugs in. I'm sure this is the case with a lot of people in smaller companies as well. Thanks for your input, I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Do have a very close look at the costs/volume/quotas - and see if you can get accurate measures of your current usage - often the standard leases will have a quota of pages - but as soon as you go over this, you start getting charged ridiculous amounts for each page.